# XSLT2.0 Remove duplicate values in node

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

I have been trying to figure out how to remove elements with duplicate values from an XML document using  XSLT.

For example:
Input:

```
<main>
   <h1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node1>New data</node1>
      <node1>New data 2</node1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
   </h1>
</main>
```

expected output:

```
<main>
   <h1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node1>New data</node1>
      <node1>New data 2</node1>
   </h1>
</main>
```

I'm sure this must not be too complicated but I am failing to understand any methods I have seen so far.
Thanks!

Thanks to Michael below!  I have a further question, if the above example had more nodes (which would never be duplicate), for example

```
 <main>
   <h1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node1>New data</node1>
      <node1>New data 2</node1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node2> Data </node2>

   </h1>
</main>
```

How would I bring this data through in the XSLT code? The below solution removes any additional data I have found despite my understanding of the identity transform to copy all, and the match to modify only matching templates.

Comment: Why not retrieve only distinct values if your values are coming from the database. Use Distinct keyword to retrieve unique values.

Comment: Hi, values are not coming from database, I have an xml that for a specified node can contain duplicated values, so I am trying to take care of these in XSLT

Comment: @MunaafGhumran, Are you sure that the order of the <node1> and <node2> elements doesn't matter? The order of elements does matter both in XML and in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node1" group-by=".">
            <node1>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </node1>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Here's another:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(node1)">
            <node1>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </node1>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To process other nodes under the `h1` header, add the following instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="* except node1"/>
```

For example (in the first case):

```
<xsl:template match="h1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node1" group-by=".">
            <node1>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </node1>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except node1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for.  I may being silly, if there were other nodes would we need to do a seperate template match on each to simply copy the data over from them?

Comment: Answered my own question through some work, was looking for xsl:copy-of and do this in the same template match

Comment: @MunaafGhumran That's one option. I have added another to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Do note that the currently accepted answer is incorrect**!

Even the 3rd solution, which doesn't lose elements is incorrect, because it doesn't preserve the order of the elements.

**Given this XML document**:

```
 <main>
   <h1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node2> Data </node2>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node1>New data</node1>
      <node1>New data 2</node1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
   </h1>
</main>
```

**the last (3rd) transformation in the accepted answer**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node1" group-by=".">
            <node1>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </node1>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except node1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces result where `<node2>` is after all `<node1>` elements** -- clearly not what one expects from an "identity" that loses duplicates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
   <h1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node1>New data</node1>
      <node1>New data 2</node1>
      <node2> Data </node2>
   </h1>
</main>
```

---

**Now a correct and very short solution** :)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kNode1ByVal" match="h1/node1" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h1/node1[not(. is key('kNode1ByVal',.)[1])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This produces the expected, correct results** -- even when applied on the above XML document -- do note that the order of the `<node1>` and `<node2>` elements is preserved!:

```
<main>
   <h1>
      <node1>duplicate</node1>
      <node2> Data </node2>
      <node1>New data</node1>
      <node1>New data 2</node1>
   </h1>
</main>
```